# Correct syntax "right= of" doesn't change "node distance"

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have been trying to position one node to the right of another.

I am using the positioning library. This is working correctly:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0){First};
\node[draw,above right =of a,node distance=200 and 100] (b){second};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is not:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0){First};
\node[draw,right =of a,node distance=200] (b){second};% correct syntax but does not shift
\node[draw,right of = a,node distance=200] (c){third};%wrong syntax but shifts
\node[draw,right =of a,node distance=400 and 400] (d){fourth};% also does not shift
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I just want the "second" node to the right of "first" node.

Comment: Usually you give a distance like `above right=200pt of a` or the like.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, but does this syntax also help in cases where we wish to use `above right` and have 100pt vertical distance and 200pt horizontal distance? I would prefer one syntax that covers all cases :(

Comment: @Andrew Edited to include commands from Torbjorn's answer to make it a MWE. Sorry, I thought the snippets were enough to understand the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easier to say

```
<position> = <node distance> of <othernode>
```

for example

```
\node [draw,right=4cm of a] {second};
\node [draw,above right=2cm and 4cm of a] {third};
```

But as for why your code didn't work, order matters it seems. Set the `node distance` *before* you set the relative position.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node[draw] (a) {First};
\node[draw,right=of a]                    (b) {second};
\node[draw,node distance=4cm, right=of a] (c) {third};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of `\node[draw,node distance=4cm, right=of a] (c) {third};` you can write shorter as`\node[draw,right=4cm of a] (c) {third};`

Comment: @Zarko I know, and I mention it in my answer, and TeXnician mentioned it in a comment on the question.  But I can rewrite a bit.

Comment: @Zarko Is it possible to use the shorter syntax to have a different vertical and horizontal distance when using e.g. `above right`? I think for casual user like me, it is preferable to have one syntax that covers all cases.

Comment: @learning2code Of course, `above right=1cm and 3cm of a`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Great! Thanks! I will mark your answer as correct, but I like this shorter syntax much better. I have a follow up question though. It appears that the distance is set between the edges of the nodes. Is there an option set the distance between the centers of the nodes instead? Not vital, but would be nice to know!

Comment: @learning2code Yes, that is the case. There is an `on grid` option for using the centre points instead.

Comment: @learning2code, i usually define `node distance` as `node distance=<vertical> and <horizontal>` common for all nodes in image and than simple use for example `below right=of <node name>`. in exception, where common distance is not gives what i like to have, i use `above right=<vertical> and <horizontal> of <node name>`.